# How to add condition before sign in in devise gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using the `devise` gem in rails project for user authentication. Now I have a problem.

I want to add a condition before the default sign in process, for example:

```
if admin?
  sign in
else
  error
end
```

And also this condition should not impact the method `sign_in_and_redirect`, because I use this method to allow user sign in with another tunnel.

I tried to override the method `active_for_authentication?`, but it also impacted the `sign_in_and_redirect`

How to implement this?

Comment: It seems like you're conflating authentication and authorization...

Comment: override create method in devise session controller.

Comment: @BradWerth Thanks, yeah, it's authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could override default sessions_controller.rb and recreate it with custom condition. Here is how to override Registration controller and it's similiar for Sessions controller: https://gist.github.com/kinopyo/2343176

Then in custom controller recreate default create action but with condition.

This is the default sessions_controller.rb https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb

This is create session action with condition

```
  # POST /resource/sign_in
  def create
    self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    if [CONDITION]
      set_flash_message!(:notice, :signed_in)
      sign_in(resource_name, resource)
      yield resource if block_given?
      respond_with resource, location: after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    else
      [ERROR]
    end
  end
```

Comment: Thanks @meshin, you idea is correct. The devise provide block interface for the `create` method. What I did finally, is provide a block to `sign_out` and `return`. Which one do you think it's the best practice?